# How to change color / appearance of EditText select handle / anchor?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-theme

So I changed the style of the Holo Theme with the [Holo Colors Generator](http://android-holo-colors.com) and [Action Bar Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.com/android-actionbarstylegenerator/) to my own color. But when I select text inside an edit text, the "markers" at the selected positions are still blue. How can I change it?

[image: Left][image: Middle][image: Right]

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40889455/how-to-change-color-of-the-bubble-under-cursor-on-editview-programmatically

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29795197/how-to-change-color-of-edittext-handles.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The worst part here was to find the "name" for this item and how it is called inside the theme. So I looked through every drawable in the android SDK folder and finally found the drawables named "text_select_handle_middle", "text_select_handle_left" and "text_select_handle_right".

So the solution is simple: Add these drawables with customized design/color to your drawable folder and add them to your theme style definition like:

```
<style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="@style/MyNotSoCustomTheme">
        <item name="android:textSelectHandle">@drawable/text_select_handle_middle</item>
        <item name="android:textSelectHandleLeft">@drawable/text_select_handle_left</item>
        <item name="android:textSelectHandleRight">@drawable/text_select_handle_right</item>
</style>
```

Comment: A little late to the party, but see my answer below on how to do this programmatically. @ant

Comment: It will work even if applied only for one EditText or TextView, not only app-wide.

Comment: Just a friendly reminder. The editView could lose response on some Samsung device after applying this solution. We just located it, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59638335/7155725)

Answer (score 13):

How to do it from code:

```
try {
    final Field fEditor = TextView.class.getDeclaredField("mEditor");
    fEditor.setAccessible(true);
    final Object editor = fEditor.get(editText);

    final Field fSelectHandleLeft = editor.getClass().getDeclaredField("mSelectHandleLeft");
    final Field fSelectHandleRight =
        editor.getClass().getDeclaredField("mSelectHandleRight");
    final Field fSelectHandleCenter =
        editor.getClass().getDeclaredField("mSelectHandleCenter");

    fSelectHandleLeft.setAccessible(true);
    fSelectHandleRight.setAccessible(true);
    fSelectHandleCenter.setAccessible(true);

    final Resources res = context.getResources();

    fSelectHandleLeft.set(editor, res.getDrawable(R.drawable.text_select_handle_left));
    fSelectHandleRight.set(editor, res.getDrawable(R.drawable.text_select_handle_right));
    fSelectHandleCenter.set(editor, res.getDrawable(R.drawable.text_select_handle_middle));
} catch (final Exception ignored) {
}
```

Comment: yes, this is one of the possible ways. but reflection is not good idea)

Comment: What if I want to change only the color of the "mSelectHandleCenter" instead of replace it with a new drawable? How can I achieve that? Unfortunately I'm forced to use reflection because I get the new "accent color" via our API

Comment: @nicopasso, https://gist.github.com/jaredrummler/2317620559d10ac39b8218a1152ec9d4 You can change that method to only color the center handle by removing the left and right field names in the two arrays.

Comment: @JaredRummler what does your drawable file look like for the text_select_handle_* files?

Comment: Can this be done from a thread? I am able to get this to work from the onCreateView of the fragment, but not from a thread. Any leads?

Comment: wish the handles were tintable so we don't have to supply our own drawables :-)

Comment: @JaredRummler Thanks..that works well..upvoted it :-)

Comment: They've added @UnsupportedAppUsage(maxTargetSdk = Build.VERSION_CODES.P) to fields, so I guess it's not working after API 28

Answer (score 13):

I recognize this is really late, but if all you want to do is change the color of the handle, you just need to add the following to your styles.xml file.

```
<style name="ColoredHandleTheme">
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorYouWant</item>
</style>
```

And then just set the theme on whatever activity is holding the `EditText` which you want to affect.

Or if you want to set it app-wide, you can do the following:

```
<style name="ColoredHandleThemeForWholeApp">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorYouWant</item>
</style>
```

And set that theme for the whole app.

Problem solved!

Comment: I don't think colorControlActivated works when setting it to the EditText directly. Only works in Activity-level (through the manifest). Tested on Nexus 5 with Android 6, and on Nexus 4 with Android 4.4.4.

Comment: Probably right. I didn't say that it would work on a single EditText. I said you could set it on an activity or app-wide.

Comment: Oh ok. Sorry and thanks. Do you know of such a solution then?

Comment: I don't sorry. Why do you want different styling on different EditTexts in the same activity?

Comment: Because if only one EditText has issue of showing its text-selection-handles (due to a background behind it), it doesn't mean all EditTexts have this issue, so it doesn't make sense to change the styles for all of them. Only for the one I'm interested in.

Comment: Speaking as a user I think it would be a bit odd to have different handle colors in an EditText, but that might just be me. Usually the accent color is used and it's a completely different color from the primary so as to stand out well.

Comment: Well, the activity is comprised of multiple fragments, and in some state of the activity, the background behind a specific EditText is similar to the default text-selection-handles, but in most cases it's just white, so it's important to have the same default one across the app, yet only in this specific case, have a different color. What do you mean about the accent color?

Comment: Usually the accent color you set for your app is the color used for the handle, I believe. Usually the accent color isn't something close to the primary color you set for the app. For some reason I was figuring your background would be using your primary color.

Comment: @androiddeveloper It will actually work if you change the theme of single EditText directly, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/35338189/1000551

Comment: @VadimKotov Wouldn't it change more than just the handles?

Comment: @androiddeveloper what do you mean? Please elaborate

Comment: @VadimKotov I mean that I think it might change more UI elements, and not just the handles. Of course, I could be wrong.

Answer (score 11):

In order to change the color of select handles, you have to override the activated color in your app theme:

```
<style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:colorControlActivated">@color/customActivatedColor</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Any way to make it work only for a specific EditText within the activity, and not all of them?

Comment: Of course you can use this style just for specific EditText's by declaring them in layout to use your custom style.

Comment: It didn't work for me on a specific EditText. Only on activity level (using the manifest). Can you please try it?

Answer (score 2):

You can see these attributes in http://androiddrawables.com/Other.html.

Change your values/styles.xml, for instance:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Cursor" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/cursor</item>
</style>
```

where @color/cursor is added in values/color.xml. After that apply the style to the activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_Cursor);
    ...
```

Visit [How to change EditText pointer color (not cursor)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33929552/how-to-change-edittext-pointer-color-not-cursor/34161273#34161273) for other solutions.

Comment: This doesn't work. Tested on Nexus 5 with Android 6 and on Nexus 4 with Android 5.

Comment: @androiddeveloper, I can't say now. I tested this code on Samsung Galaxy Tab A running Android 5. Now I think other solutions are more preferable, because they don't change colorAccent (which may affect other controls).

Answer (score 2):

For those who try to handle this from code, you can use answer provided by Jared Rummler for API version less or equal to 28, but from Android Q(API 29) they've added a @UnsupportedAppUsage(maxTargetSdk = Build.VERSION_CODES.P) annotation and it doesn't seem to work on Q+. Instead a new methods where added to EditText:

```
setTextSelectHandle(R.drawable.test);
setTextSelectHandleLeft(R.drawable.test);
setTextSelectHandleRight(R.drawable.test);
```

So, to make it work you could do something like this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                setTextSelectHandle(R.drawable.test);
                setTextSelectHandleLeft(R.drawable.test);
                setTextSelectHandleRight(R.drawable.test);
            } else {
                try {
                    final Field fEditor = TextView.class.getDeclaredField("mEditor");
                    fEditor.setAccessible(true);
                    final Object editor = fEditor.get(this);

                    final Field fSelectHandleLeft = editor.getClass().getDeclaredField("mSelectHandleLeft");
                    final Field fSelectHandleRight =
                            editor.getClass().getDeclaredField("mSelectHandleRight");
                    final Field fSelectHandleCenter =
                            editor.getClass().getDeclaredField("mSelectHandleCenter");

                    fSelectHandleLeft.setAccessible(true);
                    fSelectHandleRight.setAccessible(true);
                    fSelectHandleCenter.setAccessible(true);

                    final Resources res = getResources();

                    fSelectHandleLeft.set(editor, res.getDrawable(R.drawable.test, null));
                    fSelectHandleRight.set(editor, res.getDrawable(R.drawable.test, null));
                    fSelectHandleCenter.set(editor, res.getDrawable(R.drawable.test, null));
                } catch (final Exception ignored) {
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to hide the pointer only on one EditText you can set theme only to it:

styles.xml

```
<style name="TransparentPointerEditText">
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

usage

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/TransparentPointerEditText" />
```