# How can I change the color of arrows that appear when I am editing text

Tags: android, android-edittext

[image]

I want to change the color of arrows that appear when I am editing text in EditText , I don't know the name of these arrows,
How can I do that ?

Comment: Here's an approach: [Android: Change color / appearance of EditText Select Handle / Anchor](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15133928/2558882).

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by using a custom theme and setting the following:

```
<item name="android:textSelectHandle">@drawable/text_select_handle_middle</item>
<item name="android:textSelectHandleLeft">@drawable/text_select_handle_left</item>
<item name="android:textSelectHandleRight">@drawable/text_select_handle_right</item>
```

Or, you can use reflection:

```
try {
    final Field fEditor = TextView.class.getDeclaredField("mEditor");
    fEditor.setAccessible(true);
    final Object editor = fEditor.get(editText);

    final Field fSelectHandleLeft = editor.getClass().getDeclaredField("mSelectHandleLeft");
    final Field fSelectHandleRight =
        editor.getClass().getDeclaredField("mSelectHandleRight");
    final Field fSelectHandleCenter =
        editor.getClass().getDeclaredField("mSelectHandleCenter");

    fSelectHandleLeft.setAccessible(true);
    fSelectHandleRight.setAccessible(true);
    fSelectHandleCenter.setAccessible(true);

    final Resources res = context.getResources();

    fSelectHandleLeft.set(editor, res.getDrawable(R.drawable.text_select_handle_left));
    fSelectHandleRight.set(editor, res.getDrawable(R.drawable.text_select_handle_right));
    fSelectHandleCenter.set(editor, res.getDrawable(R.drawable.text_select_handle_middle));
} catch (final Exception ignored) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can change that without changing the keyboard layout, which will have to be done separately and here are some tutorials on how to do it:

[LINK1](http://github.com/chrisboyle/sgtpuzzles/blob/master/src/name/boyle/chris/sgtpuzzles/SmallKeyboard.java)

[LINK2](http://code.google.com/p/nethack-android/)

[LINK3](https://github.com/rciovati/Android-KeyboardView-Example)

[LINK4](https://code.google.com/p/hackerskeyboard/source/checkout)

[LINK5](https://github.com/alanszlosek/android-keyboard)

[LINK6](https://github.com/dhaval0122/keyboard_sample_2#readme)

EDIT:

For the hint color, you can also set a red color for example, see if this does the trick:

```
android:textColorHint="#FF0000"
```

Comment: I think it should be more simple ! I just need to change a color

Comment: Unfortunatelly I didn't find anything regarding this problem, but I'm not a criteria for this, so good luck at finding the solution! Please poste the answer here if you find one ok ?

Comment: I've made an EDIT, check it out .. :)