# How to change color of EditText handles?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-styles

Where does the green color comes from? I've tried changing the `accentColor` attribute, which works in other parts of the app, but not here.

[image: editText Colors]
Screenshot from app in Lollipop.

How can I change the colors of:

- the text handle drawables? how to tint them?
- the select-all-background color?

And maybe some tips for the future... How did you find out? I've been coming across all these confusing color/styling problems. Is there some kind of list somewhere that tells me, which default color or attribute that I need to overwrite for a certain component?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change color / appearance of EditText select handle / anchor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133926/how-to-change-color-appearance-of-edittext-select-handle-anchor)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For changing the handle color you can do as specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15133928/3831557) you do it using style as

```
<style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="@style/MyNotSoCustomTheme">
        <item name="android:textSelectHandle">@drawable/text_select_handle_middle</item>
        <item name="android:textSelectHandleLeft">@drawable/text_select_handle_left</item>
        <item name="android:textSelectHandleRight">@drawable/text_select_handle_right</item>
</style>
```

For doing it programmatically check same question another reply [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27307004/3831557) which is done using reflection

```
try {
    final Field fEditor = TextView.class.getDeclaredField("mEditor");
    fEditor.setAccessible(true);
    final Object editor = fEditor.get(editText);

    final Field fSelectHandleLeft = editor.getClass().getDeclaredField("mSelectHandleLeft");
    final Field fSelectHandleRight = editor.getClass().getDeclaredField("mSelectHandleRight");
    final Field fSelectHandleCenter = editor.getClass().getDeclaredField("mSelectHandleCenter");

    fSelectHandleLeft.setAccessible(true);
    fSelectHandleRight.setAccessible(true);
    fSelectHandleCenter.setAccessible(true);

    final Resources res = context.getResources();

    fSelectHandleLeft.set(editor, res.getDrawable(R.drawable.text_select_handle_left));
    fSelectHandleRight.set(editor, res.getDrawable(R.drawable.text_select_handle_right));
    fSelectHandleCenter.set(editor, res.getDrawable(R.drawable.text_select_handle_middle));
} catch (final Exception ignored) {
}
```

For changing the selected text color you can set `textColorHighlight` in xml as

```
android:textColorHighlight="#ff0000"
```

through style you can do as

```
<item name="android:textColorHighlight">@color/m_highlight_blue</item>
```

Comment: thanks for helping, I liked both answers, but yours was more about the text handlers. I guess there is no way of just tinting them? yeah maybe get the drawable first and then tint it...

Comment: Thanks! `<item name="android:textColorHighlight">@color/m_highlight_blue</item>` changes a selection color.

Answer (score 4):

Make changes to your styles.xml as follows

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/accent_translucent</item>
    <item name="android:colorControlHighlight">@color/accent_translucent</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="selectableItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_item_background</item>
    <item name="android:selectableItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_item_background</item>

</style>

<color name="primary">#00BCD4</color>
<color name="primary_dark">#0097A7</color>
<color name="accent">#FFEB3B</color>
<color name="accent_translucent">#80FFEB3B</color>
<color name="accent_bright">#FFF493</color>
```

Or you can add a XML attribute to your EditText

```
android:textColorHighlight="@color/accent_translucent"
```

Hope it solves your problem.

Comment: I also like your answer, because it sets the colors over the whole app. Just one weird thing I havent figured out yet. One of my edittexts does not take over the theme and the other edittext does... Do you maybe know, of a condition when edittexts do not take over the styling? maybe wrong inflating issue?

Comment: Thanks @Lokkio . No, I haven't faced such issues. It may be due to inflating issues.