# how to change the color of the edittext text selection handles?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-theme, android-styles

i know this question was already answered but i can't find a solution that work.

on android > lolipop (21) is their any way to change the color of my text selection handles (without uploading new png image)?

i define this style

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

  <style name="AppEditTextStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.EditText">
    <item name="android:background">@null</item>    
    <item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@null</item> 
    <item name="android:drawableTint">#00ffffff</item>           
  </style>

  <style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar"> 
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/AppEditTextStyle</item>
  </style>

</resources>
```

but it's not work, i receive :
Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:drawableTint'.

but in the doc (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:drawableTint) it is clearly specified that android:drawableTint exist :( so i don't understand why i miss ?

Comment: Loki this might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29795197/how-to-change-color-of-edittext-handlers

Comment: thanks W4R10CK but no :( i don't want to do <item name="android:textSelectHandle">@drawable/text_select_handle_middle</item> because i know that on android > 21 their is a way to change the color wihtout uploading new drawables. i don't understand for now why <item name="android:drawableTint">#00ffffff</item>  return an error :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change color of EditText handles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29795197/how-to-change-color-of-edittext-handles)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In android lolipop and later the handles color is the accent color.

I suggest to read this:

[Selection - Patterns - Material design guidelines](https://material.google.com/patterns/selection.html#selection-text-selection)

Here is the styles line:

```
<item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
```

And set selection color like this:

```
android:textColorHighlight="@color/colorAccent"
```

Comment: but when i do <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item> i receive No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorAccent' :(

Comment: can we add the <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item> only to one TextEdit instead of defining it globally ?

Comment: `colorAccent` for handles will work only if set in Activity's theme