# How to change textSelectHandle color for an EditText

Tags: android

Android has a default green tear drop that appears under the text to help select text or position. How can I change the color of it without `@drawable`s? I tried  `android:textSelectHandle="@color/colorPrimary"` but that just made it disappear.

```
<EditText
  android:inputType="text"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imgMagnifyingGlass"
  android:textAlignment="viewStart"
  android:backgroundTint="@color/colorWhite"
  android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
  android:textSelectHandle="@color/colorPrimary"
  android:textColor="@color/colorGray"
  android:id="@+id/editTextWord" />
```

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29795197/how-to-change-color-of-edittext-handles

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I fixed it by adding this to my styles.xml:

```
<item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimary</item>
```

All the other accepted answers on this topic involve `@drawable`s and this seems the simplest way.