# What are these theme attributes in an EditText for?

Tags: android, kotlin

I was just checking out the attributes for my `EditText` and I came upon these strange attributes:

[image]

Can someone tell me what they are for???

My `minSdkVersion`:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the references to the drawables, to display text selection and left/right anchors, as written [in the documentation](http://%20https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#attr_android:textSelectHandle).

[In this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29795197/how-to-change-color-of-edittext-handles) you can see how to change the colors of those.