# Changing highlighted text color

Tags: android, text

I have just a edittext on a card, created with relativelayout. When i double press on it, to mark it, the color of the two markes, right and left from the text a bit lower, have the same color as the card, because of that i want to change the color of the markers. The bar above the toolbar, and under the statusbar, is currently white, how u can see on the picture, that i want to change too, with animations and colors :D Maybe somebody can help me at my difficulties

Thanks in advance :)

It looks currently like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using `android:textColorHighlight` in your edit text

Comment: that only change the color of the marked text, but noch from the pointers :/ thx otherwise :)

Comment: Checkout if this thread can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133926/android-change-color-appearance-of-edittext-select-handle-anchor

Answer (score 0):

Just got the answer by myself :D I just pasted following line in my styles.xml

```
<item name="colorControlActivated">#607D8B</item>
```