# how to programatically set textColorHint to TextInputLayout?

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

I am trying to create `editText` having floating hint using Android `TextInputLayout`.
I want to reuse the same `TextInputLayout` in two layouts.But in both the layout hint color is different.
I searched through several links and found that we can set hint color in edittext(not the floating hint color) by adding

`android:textColorHint="@color/white"` in `TextInputLayout`.

But how to do it programatically as in other layout color needs to be different

PS: `setTextAppearanceHint()` is not working.

Comment: you are using edittext inside TextInputLayout. right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the floating hint color of TextInputLayout if EditText inside is disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35738544/how-to-change-the-floating-hint-color-of-textinputlayout-if-edittext-inside-is-d)

Comment: Try this:
[kotlin version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57184478/10997485) Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Try with [**`setHintTextAppearance`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html#setHintTextAppearance(int))

```
setHintTextAppearance(R.style.my_style);
```

Then

```
<style name="my_style" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
<item name="android:textColor">#54D66A</item>
```

For more details you can check [**`TextInputLayout accent color programmatically`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37746541/3395198).

Comment: It is changing the color of floating label hint i.e when edittext is in focus.I want to set the color of hint inside edittext when it is not not in focus.

Comment: setHintTextColor doenot exist for TextInputLayout

Comment: exactly why are you giving setHintTextColor to TextInputLayout. GIve it to edit text.

Comment: @ShwetaChauhan Think so .

Comment: gicing hint color to edittext that is wrapped in textinputlayout wont work.We need to set hintcolor to textinputlayout only

Comment: go through this : https://medium.com/@Gryzor/styling-textinputlayout-and-textinputedittext-on-android-9ab786bef7af

Comment: <item name="textColor">@color/gray</item> changes the color of floating hint when edittext is in focus,not the color of the hint when it is not in focus.

Comment: @stackLearner check Possible duplicate link in comment section.

Comment: @stackLearner any solutions yet?

Comment: As per documentation,i cant find any method which can programatically replace textHintColor attribute of TextInputLayout.It can be set only through xml.

Comment: This is the best solution ,i can see .Thanks @IntelliJAmiya

Comment: @stackLearner Move ahead.

Answer (score 0):

You can give this a try.
The TextView in TextInputLayout has an id `R.id.textinput_error`

So,

```
tv = (TextView) textInputLayout.findViewById(R.id.textinput_error);
tv.setTextColor(int resId);
```

Comment: `create editText having floating hint using Android TextInputLayout` so why `TextView`