# Edit Appearance of EditText Select Handle

Tags: android, android-styles

I have been trying to customize the EditText Select Handle color by following the question and response laid out here: [How to change color / appearance of EditText select handle / anchor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133926/android-change-color-appearance-of-edittext-select-handle-anchor), and I have been running into some issues.

First, I added a new item to my custom style:

**styles_home.xml**

```
 <item name="android:textSelectHandle">@drawable/text_select_handle_midde</item>
```

Next, I anded a new drawable resource to match, copying in the the file I found in the android sdk:

**text_select_handle_middle.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/text_select_handle_middle_mtrl_alpha"
    android:tint="?attr/colorControlActivated" />
```

This is actually copied from the `text_handle_middle_material.xml` in the android-21 sdk.

The problem I am running into is the `@drawable/text_select_handle_middle_mtrl_alpha` does not exist and it is not contained as far as I can tell in the sdk.

So, my question is where is this file located / how do people update this?