# How to change EditText pointer color (not cursor)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-widget, textview

I'm trying to make the pointer color of `EditText` to become blue.

[image: Droplet looking thing is the pointer]

I'm able to make the underline and the cursor to become blue, but the droplet looking pointer is still grey.

I google a bit, but all the links that appear only talk about how to change the cursor, not the pointer. So if anybody knows how to do this, I need your help.

I only need to support Android 5.0 and above. So if your solution only works on API > 21, that's totally fine.

Thanks!

Comment: That's a duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133926/android-change-color-appearance-of-edittext-select-handle-anchor.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

in your styles.xml put like this:

```
<item name="colorAccent">@color/blue</item>
```

Comment: This is not a good solution. It changes cursor color for all views in an application. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133926/android-change-color-appearance-of-edittext-select-handle-anchor for a right solution.

Comment: if we want to keep the accent color same but change the color of text selector pointer only for one particular EditText then how to do it ?

Comment: @CoolMind You can set it on a specific activity as well, you don't need to set the theme on every activity.

Comment: This solution is not valid for Android version 5.0. It changes everything: cursor, handler and underlininig.

Comment: It also changes the underline color. What if we want different colors for both underline and pointer

Answer (score 9):

I recognize this is really late, but if all you want to do is change the color of the handle, you just need to add the following to your styles.xml file.

```
<style name="ColoredHandleTheme">
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorYouWant</item>
</style>
```

Or if you want to set it app-wide, you can do the following:

```
<style name="ColoredHandleThemeForWholeApp">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorYouWant</item>
</style>
```

And then just set the theme on whatever activity is holding the `EditText` which you want to affect.

Problem solved!

Comment: It also changes the underline color. What if we want different colors for both underline and pointer

Answer (score 0):

You may use "textSelectHandle" and set a custom drawable to get the desired output. As shown below -

```
<style name="MyCustomTheme">
    <item name="android:textSelectHandle">@drawable/middle_icon</item>
</style>
```