# How do I change the color of the blob on an Android EditText view?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-theme

I'm trying to style an `EditText` but can't seem to find the right style for one of the UI elements. I don't even know it's name, which is slowing me down a bit :)

The background for this `EditText` is going to be my theme's primary color (the dark pink in the picture - I've temporarily changed it to light pink so we can see what's happening in a screenshot).

Unfortunately, the teardrop shaped blob is also the primary color, but I can't find a way to change its color.

My question is

a) What's the teardrop shape called?!

and

b) How do I change its color on this `EditText`?

Thanks.

[image: EditText showing the cursor and blob]

Comment: Have you read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33929552/how-to-change-edittext-pointer-color-not-cursor ?

Comment: I had not. I'll flag this question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change it for all `EditText` with setting the accent color in `AppTheme`:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorPrimary">#FF5722</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">#CDDC39</item>
    </style>
```

Or just for a single EditText using `Theme` on your `EditText`:

```
<style name="MyEditText" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">#FF5722</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">#CDDC39</item>
    </style>
```

After that apply your `@style` on the `EditText`:

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Hint text"
        android:theme="@style/MyEditText"
        />
```

**Result:**

[image: Result]