# EditText cursor and pointer not changing colour properly

Tags: android, android-edittext, xamarin.android, android-styles

I have an application that has 4 styles, each one has a different `colorAccent`. Depending on the user actions, the style being used may change, and so does the `colorAccent`.

There's also two *`somewhat-static`* `EditText` views ( *these view won't disappear on the app's lifecycle, since they are present in the "Home" page of the app* ). For reference, let's assume that I have:

#### 2 Views

- `EditTextA`
- `EditTextB`

#### 4 Styles

- `StyleR` with `Red` as `colorAccent`
- `StyleG` with `Green` as `colorAccent`
- `StyleB` with `Blue` as `colorAccent`
- `StyleY` with `Yellow` as `colorAccent`

If I have `StyleR` as the current style and tap the `EditTextA` the cursor will immediately appear coloured red. If I change the style to `StyleG`, tap the `EditTextA`, type something and select it, I'll have a **red** cursor with a **green** pointer beneath it. Meanwhile, if I tap the `EditTextB`, the cursor will be **green**.

I've tried to `Invalidate()` and `PostInvalidate()` both views within the `RunOnUiThread`, but they wouldn't correct their colours.

Any other `EditText` that is inflated between the style changes get the correct colour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this answer by Jared Rummler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40889455/how-to-change-color-of-the-bubbleunder-cursor-on-editview-programatically), I've managed to do what I want in Xamarin. This is the code I ended up with:

```
public static void SetCursorColor( this EditText editText, Resources resources, Int32 colorResourceId ) {
    try {
        TextView
            textViewTemplate = new TextView( editText.Context );

        //
        // EditText Cursor
        //
        var field = textViewTemplate.Class.GetDeclaredField( "mCursorDrawableRes" );
        field.Accessible = true;
        Int32 drawableResId = field.GetInt( editText );

        field = textViewTemplate.Class.GetDeclaredField( "mEditor" );
        field.Accessible = true;
        var editor = field.Get( editText );

        Drawable drawable = resources.GetDrawable( drawableResId );
        drawable.SetColorFilter( resources.GetColor( colorResourceId ), PorterDuff.Mode.SrcIn );
        Drawable[] drawables = { drawable, drawable };

        field = editor.Class.GetDeclaredField( "mCursorDrawable" );
        field.Accessible = true;
        field.Set( editor, drawables );

        //
        // EditText Pointer
        //
        String[]
            fieldsNames = { "mTextSelectHandleLeftRes", "mTextSelectHandleRightRes", "mTextSelectHandleRes" },
            drawablesNames = { "mSelectHandleLeft", "mSelectHandleRight", "mSelectHandleCenter" };

        for( Int32 index = 0; index < fieldsNames.Length && index < drawablesNames.Length; index++ ) {
            String
                fieldName = fieldsNames[ index ],
                drawableName = drawablesNames[ index ];

            field = textViewTemplate.Class.GetDeclaredField( fieldName );
            field.Accessible = true;
            Int32 handle = field.GetInt( editText );

            Drawable handleDrawable = resources.GetDrawable( handle );
            handleDrawable.SetColorFilter( resources.GetColor( colorResourceId ), PorterDuff.Mode.SrcIn );

            field = editor.Class.GetDeclaredField( drawableName );
            field.Accessible = true;
            field.Set( editor, handleDrawable );
        }
    } catch( Exception exception ) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed only white cursor and pointer for Android project, and based on "auhmaan" answer I wrote this code in Droid Renderer and it works. Perhaps it can be helpful for someone:

```
if (Control != null && Element != null)
{
    // set the cursor color the same as the entry TextColor
    IntPtr IntPtrtextViewClass = JNIEnv.FindClass(typeof(TextView));
    IntPtr mCursorDrawableResProperty =
    JNIEnv.GetFieldID(IntPtrtextViewClass, "mCursorDrawableRes", "I");
    // replace 0 with a Resource.Drawable.my_cursor 
    JNIEnv.SetField(Control.Handle, mCursorDrawableResProperty, 0);

    try
        {
            TextView textViewTemplate = new TextView(Control.Context);

            var field = textViewTemplate.Class.GetDeclaredField("mEditor");
            field.Accessible = true;
            var editor = field.Get(Control);

            //
            // EditText Pointer
            //
            String[]
            fieldsNames = { "mTextSelectHandleLeftRes", "mTextSelectHandleRightRes", "mTextSelectHandleRes" },
            drawablesNames = { "mSelectHandleLeft", "mSelectHandleRight", "mSelectHandleCenter" };

            for (Int32 index = 0; index < fieldsNames.Length && index < drawablesNames.Length; index++)
                {
                    String
                    fieldName = fieldsNames[index],
                    drawableName = drawablesNames[index];

                    field = textViewTemplate.Class.GetDeclaredField(fieldName);
                    field.Accessible = true;
                    Int32 handle = field.GetInt(Control);

                    Drawable handleDrawable = Resources.GetDrawable(handle);

                  handleDrawable.SetColorFilter(Xamarin.Forms.Color.White.ToAndroid(), PorterDuff.Mode.SrcIn);

                    field = editor.Class.GetDeclaredField(drawableName);
                    field.Accessible = true;
                    field.Set(editor, handleDrawable);
                }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```