# How to change color of the bubble (under cursor) on EditText in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I change the color of the bubble that appears upon text selection in a Text or TextFormField or .. in Flutter?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40889455/how-to-change-color-of-the-bubble-under-cursor-on-edittext-programmatically) is the same question but for native code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may use the [textSelectionHandleColor](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData/textSelectionHandleColor.html) property.

```
Theme(
          data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
            textSelectionHandleColor: Colors.green, 
          ),
          child: TextField(),
        );
```

Answer (score 13):

According to [this flutter documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/text-selection-theme), `textSelectionHandleColor` is deprecated. You should use `selectionHandleColor` instead inside `TextSelectionThemeData` widget like the code below.

```
  theme: ThemeData(
   
    textSelectionTheme: TextSelectionThemeData(
      cursorColor: Colors.red,
      selectionColor: Colors.green,
      selectionHandleColor: Colors.black,
    ),
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of iOS `TextField`, i've found no other solution than adding the snippet below to the top level MaterialApp like this:

`MaterialApp` => `theme: ThemeData( snippet )`

snippet:
`cupertinoOverrideTheme: CupertinoThemeData( primaryColor: Color(0xff554270), ),`

i couldn't apply this snippet by wrapping the `TextField` with `Theme(data: Theme.of(context).copyWith( ...` did not work.. dunno why ]: (maybe this one would be my fault in somewhere but adding it to the app lv definitely worked tho)

Hope this answer help future iOS wanderers [: