# In Android Studio how to change the cursor?

Tags: android, android-studio, cursor, selector

**
By using xml or design I want to change the color of cursor when i start writing i n plain text from default color to another one .. how i can do this please**

Comment: Are you asking about the cursor for `EditTexts`?

Comment: Do you mean the cursor within Android Studio (since you use that tag) or do you actually mean on Android?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change EditText bubble color (under cursor) in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35337909/how-to-change-edittext-bubble-color-under-cursor-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Easy way(For API level>=21)**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">

    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/your_cursor_color</item>
</style>
```

**Better way(For all API levels)**

1.Define `android:textCursorDrawable` in your layout

```
<EditText  
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/color_cursor"
    />
```

2.Create a cursor in drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <size android:width="2.5dp" />
    <solid android:color="color_cursor"  />
</shape>
```