# Change Android TextField's Select Cursor

Tags: android, android-studio, android-xml

I need to change the color of this pink stuff. I'm not sure if that's a cursor or not. My theory is that it's based on the device preferences. When I tried showing that stuff in other app in my simulator, they are in different colors.

[image]

What I did:

1. Searching on SO, but to no avail.
2. Changed this attribute. - the blinking cursor was the only thing affected by this property.

   ```
   android:textCursorDrawable
   ```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change color / appearance of EditText select handle / anchor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133926/how-to-change-color-appearance-of-edittext-select-handle-anchor)

Comment: Agreed. What step should I take if it's a duplicate? Close or Delete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not an cursor it an cursor pointer color so you can change that pointer color by means of changing the theme

**ColorAccent :**

```
<style name="EditTextColorCustom" parent="@style/AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>//your color here
</style>
```

**Step2:**

In your styles.xml put like this:

```
<item name="colorAccent">@color/reddish</item>
```

Comment: sorry, I'm a newbie in Android, where do I put the Color  Accent? :(

Comment: Inside -->res--->color.xml file

Comment: thanks guys!!! You could just say: "just change the colorAccent's value". That's it.