# Setting color of marked text of textfield

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-relativelayout, android-textinputedittext, xml-layout

[image: example]

I was looking for an answer, but I wonder why nobody asks this kind of question. Maybe I just formualted it wrong.
Basically, the only thing I want i to change the marker color from Purple->Orange, but I can't find the correspondive `android:` attribute to do so. Is there an attribute where I can change the color?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change color / appearance of EditText select handle / anchor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133926/how-to-change-color-appearance-of-edittext-select-handle-anchor)

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

[image]

As far as I know this comes from the colorAccent defined in your styles.xml, colors.xml. Changing it there did the trick for me. Hope it helps.

Comment: this just changes the color of cyan->orange but not the purple marker to orange

Comment: I've edited my reply above, hope if helps.